# Nested lists to nested dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary, enumerate

I've a list with master keys and a list of list of lists, where the first value of each enclosed list (like `'key_01'`) shall be a sub key for the corresponding values (like `'val_01', 'val_02'`). The data is shown here:

```
master_keys = ["Master_01", "Master_02", "Master_03"]
data_long = [[['key_01','val_01','val_02'],['key_02','val_03','val_04'], ['key_03','val_05','val_06']],
           [['key_04','val_07','val_08'], ['key_05','val_09','val_10'], ['key_06','val_11','val_12']],
           [['key_07','val_13','val_14'], ['key_08','val_15','val_16'], ['key_09','val_17','val_18']]]
```

I would like these lists to be combined into a dictionary of dictionaries, like this:

```
master_dic = {
"Master_01": {'key_01':['val_01','val_02'],'key_02': ['val_03','val_04'], 'key_03': ['val_05','val_06']}, 
"Master_02": {'key_04': ['val_07','val_08'], 'key_05': ['val_09','val_10'], 'key_06': ['val_11','val_12']}, 
"Master_03": {'key_07': ['val_13','val_14'], ['key_08': ['val_15','val_16'], 'key_09': ['val_17','val_18']}
}
```

What I've got so far is the sub dict:

```
import itertools

master_dic = {}
servant_dic = {}
keys = []
values = []
for line in data_long:
    for item in line:
        keys.extend(item[:1])
        values.append(item[1:])
servant_dic = dict(itertools.izip(keys, values))
```

Which puts out a dictionary, as expected.

```
servant_dic = {
'key_06': ['val_11','val_12'], 'key_04': ['val_08','val_07'], 'key_05': ['val_09','val_10'], 
'key_02': ['val_03','val_04'], 'key_03': ['val_05','val_06'], 'key_01': ['val_01','val_02']
 }
```

The problem is, that if I want to add the master_keys to this dictionary, so I get the wanted result, I'd have to do this in a certain order, which would be possible, if each line had a counter like this:

```
enumerated_dic =
{
0: {'key_01':['val_01','val_02'],'key_02': ['val_03','val_04'], 'key_03': ['val_05','val_06']}, 
1: {'key_04': ['val_07','val_08'], 'key_05': ['val_09','val_10'], 'key_06': ['val_11','val_12']}, 
2: {'key_07': ['val_13','val_14'], ['key_08': ['val_15','val_16'], 'key_09': ['val_17','val_18']}
}
```

I'd love to do this with `enumerate()`, while each line of the `servant_dic` is build, but can't figure out how. Since afterwards, i could simply replace the counters 0, 1, 2 etc. with the `master_keys`.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
master_keys = ["Master_01", "Master_02", "Master_03"]
data_long = [[['key_01','val_01','val_02'],['key_02','val_03','val_04'], ['key_03','val_05','val_06']],
           [['key_04','val_07','val_08'], ['key_05','val_09','val_10'], ['key_06','val_11','val_12']],
           [['key_07','val_13','val_14'], ['key_08','val_15','val_16'], ['key_09','val_17','val_18']]]


_dict = {}

for master_key, item in zip(master_keys, data_long):
    _dict[master_key] = {x[0]: x[1:] for x in item}

print _dict
```

Comment: After reading up on `zip()` (again), it dawned on me. @turkus and @ig-melnyk, your approach really taught me, what I wanted to learn here, thanks! @mpiskore, the approach using `.pop()`, to me, is a very creative one. I do like it.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help:

```
{master_key: {i[0]: i[1:] for i in subkeys} for master_key, subkeys in zip(master_keys, data_long)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `pop` and a dict comprehension:

```
for key, elements in zip(master_keys, data_long):
    print {key: {el.pop(0): el for el in elements}}
   ...:
{'Master_01': {'key_02': ['val_03', 'val_04'], 'key_03': ['val_05', 'val_06']}}
{'Master_02': {'key_06': ['val_11', 'val_12'], 'key_04': ['val_07', 'val_08'], 'key_05': ['val_09', 'val_10']}}
{'Master_03': {'key_07': ['val_13', 'val_14'], 'key_08': ['val_15', 'val_16'], 'key_09': ['val_17', 'val_18']}}
```

Answer (score 1):

My functional approach:

```
master_dic = dict(zip(master_keys, [{k[0]: k[1::] for k in emb_list} for emb_list in data_long]))
print(master_dic)
```